# Alsa audio problem on Mint 19.10

Tags: linux-mint, audio, alsa

I have an issue with audio on my laptop ( Distorced / none ). I changed many distributions, reinstalled many different packages on the distros, but the problem remains. Now I have Mint 19.10 (MATE).

I share some output :

**systemctl status alsa-state.service**

```
● alsa-state.service - Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-state.service; static; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2019-11-29 16:47:25 CET; 30min ago
           └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf was not met
     Docs: man:alsactl(1)
```

**systemctl status alsa-utils.service**

```
● alsa-utils.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

**systemctl status alsa-restore.service**

```
● alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static; vendor pres
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-11-29 16:47:25 CET; 33min ago
     Docs: man:alsactl(1)
```

**dmesg | grep snd | head -8**

```
[    6.765935] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.766362] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    6.811820] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC294: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    6.811824] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.811827] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.811829] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    6.811840] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    6.811866] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
```

**ll /lib/systemd/system | grep alsa**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   539 Feb 15  2017 alsa-restore.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   512 Feb 15  2017 alsa-state.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov 29 15:10 alsa-utils.service -> /dev/null
```

**cat /proc/asound/modules**

```
 0 snd_hda_intel
```

**cat /proc/asound/cards**

```
 0 [PCH            ]: 
HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xef328000 irq 131
```

Comment: suggest use 'alsa-info.sh' and edit post to include link to ALSA data